# How can I clone a specific Site in Craft, not the default?

Tags: craft3, multi-site, sites

I have many sites in Craft and I group them by language. For example, German has Germany and Austria sites in them. Spanish has Spain, Mexico and Colombia.

The sections are set to propagate entries across sites.

When we need to create a new site, the entries from the others are created, because of the propagation, BUT they are created from the default English site. So if we create a site in say the Spanish group, it does not create the entries from the other Spanish content, but it creates it from the default site which is in the English group.

How can we create a site and have it created from the group we add it into?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this issue and imagine there will be a better solution in the future, but for now you can change your default site to the one you want to duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't that mean the main site on the front end changes? I thought I read that somewhere. But then maybe it doesn't due to the sites base url being set. So I could give it a try, but it doesnt sound right to me. I have in the meantime written a controller action to sync titles and slugs and uris between the first site in the group and the new site, and that seems to work.

Comment: Craft says this so its only when it cant determine a site it shows the default one so may be OK "Craft sets the default site as the Primary site, meaning Craft will load it by default on the front end, if it is unable to determine which site to load."